# What's the benefits of using repo instead of git

Tags: android

Google introduced repo to manage Android source code. As is said in the document, repo is meant to make it easier to work with Android. I can't see why from the documents at

https://source.android.com/source/developing.html

From what I am seeing in the document, repo just create synonyms from git commands. So how repo makes it easier to work with Android?

Comment: Quoting the documentation that you linked to: "Repo unifies the many Git repositories when necessary, does the uploads to our [revision control system](https://android-review.googlesource.com/), and automates parts of the Android development workflow... For example, with a single Repo command you can download files from multiple repositories into your local working directory." That seems fairly self-explanatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you have already read:

> Repo is a repository management tool that we built on top of Git. Repo
>   unifies the many Git repositories when necessary, does the uploads to
>   our revision control system, and automates parts of the Android
>   development workflow. Repo is not meant to replace Git, only to make
>   it easier to work with Git in the context of Android. The repo command
>   is an executable Python script that you can put anywhere in your path.
>   In working with the Android source files, you will use Repo for
>   across-network operations. For example, with a single Repo command you
>   can download files from multiple repositories into your local working
>   directory.

Simply put, it meant for managing multiple git repositories.

This is to make the development process more modular as you can have each feature developed in its own repository. That way, each team can contribute to their own separate repository. Each of the repositories often come together to create a larger project.

Repo allows you to pull specific commit points from each git repository to create a collective snapshot for the larger project.